# Extracting factor scores from svyfactanal

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I was trying to run a factor analysis by using the `svyfactanal()` function and getting factor scores. There is no problem with running the factor analysis.

```
library(survey)
factor1 <- svyfactanal(~  var1 + var2 + var3 ... + var12, 
                       design = design, factors = 4, rotation = "promax", 
                       scores = "regression")
```

However, when I want to extract the factor scores for each observation I receive an error message:

```
data1 <- cbind(data, factor1$scores)
```

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 1297, 0

Then I check the factor scores manually, and I received this message:

```
factor1$scores
# NULL
```

Is there a way to extract these scores from the `svyfactanal()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svyfactanal just passes a different covariance matrix to factanal.  In the documentation for factanal, the scores are in $scores e.g. (from the help):

```
v1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6)
v2 <- c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,4,3,3,3,4,6,5)
v3 <- c(3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,4,6)
v4 <- c(3,3,4,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,5,6,4)
v5 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,6,4,5)
v6 <- c(1,1,1,2,1,3,3,3,4,3,1,1,1,2,1,6,5,4)
m1 <- cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6)
cor(m1)
factanal(m1, factors = 3) # varimax is the default
factanal(m1, factors = 3, rotation = "promax")
# The following shows the g factor as PC1
prcomp(m1) # signs may depend on platform

## formula interface
factanal(~v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6, factors = 3,
         scores = "Bartlett")$scores
```

If you wanted just the first factor scores, you would use:

```
factanal(~v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6, factors = 3,
         scores = "Bartlett")$scores[,1]
```

or, for your example, something like:

```
factor1scores <- factor1$scores[,1]
data1 <- cbind(data, factor1scores)
```